# $A,B,C \in F $ A,B,C independent $P(ABC)=P(A)P(B)P(C)$ Prove: $A \Delta C$ and $B$ are independent.

Tags: probability

$A,B,C \in F $ A,B,C independent $P(ABC)=P(A)P(B)P(C)$ Prove: $A \Delta C$ and $B$ are independent.

I tried $$P((A \Delta C)B)=P(((A\C) \cup (C\A))B)=P((A\C)B \cup(C\A)B)=P)(A\C)B)+P((C\A)B)-0=P(AC^cB)+P(A^cCB)$$ I also know that $P(AC^c)=P(A)P(C^c)$, what i don;t know if i can do is :$P(AC^cB)=P(AC^c)P(B)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: $A, B, C$ independent means $A, B$, $A, C$ and $B, C$ are also independent.

You have $P(A\cap C^c) = P(A) - P(A\cap C) = P(A) - P(A)P(C)
= P(A)(1 - P(C)) = P(A)P(C^c).$

Can you do the rest?

In response to you comment I show a little more.

You have $P((A - C)\cap B) = P(A\cap C^c \cap B)
= P(A\cap B) - P(A\cap B\cap C) = P(A)P(B) - P(A)P(B)P(C)
= P(A)P(B)(1 - P(C)) = P(A)P(B)P(C^c).$

Comment: This, i'm aware of, it's the rest i can't put together..

Comment: In my notation AB means A $\cap$ B